# Why does value appended to list change dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dynamic

Python Version: 3.9.5

My Code:

```
cells = [[i, i] for i in range(3)]
steps = []

for t in range(2):
    for i in range(len(cells)):
        xrand = random.randint(-5, 5)
        yrand = random.randint(-5, 5)
        cells[i][0] += xrand
        cells[i][1] += yrand
    steps.append(list(cells))
    print(steps)
```

Actual Output:

```
[[[3, 3], [2, 3], [6, 3]]]
[[[4, 7], [-3, 2], [8, 3]], [[4, 7], [-3, 2], [8, 3]]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[[3, 3], [2, 3], [6, 3]]]
[[[3, 3], [2, 3], [6, 3]], [[4, 7], [-3, 2], [8, 3]]]
```

I am changing the value of the list **cells** every time in the outer loop and appending the modified list to the **steps** list. As you can see in the output, in the second iteration, the first element of **cells** is also modified even though I am only appending an element to the list.

The first element of **steps** is the **cells** list from the previous iteration. But in the second iteration, both elements dynamically change even though I am only appending an element and so the first element shouldn't be affected.

Why does this happen and how do you overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

`list(cells)` creates a shallow copy, thus modifying the mutable content of `cells` will also mutate the contents of the shallow copy - or rather, the content of the shallow copy is really **the same object** as the content of `cells`.

What you want is a deep copy:

```
import copy

cells = [[i, i] for i in range(3)]
steps = []

for t in range(2):
    for i in range(len(cells)):
        xrand = 1
        yrand = 1
        cells[i][0] += xrand
        cells[i][1] += yrand
    steps.append(copy.deepcopy(cells))
    print(steps)
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]]
[[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], [[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]]
```

I have replaced the `random.randint` parts with static values, so the demonstrated output is less ... random.

Answer (score 0):

**Lists are manipulated in place**

This is because the list is manipulated with a reference to the real object (storage location) on the disk. See the following example:

```python
l = [2]
x = [l, l]
print(x)
>>> [[2], [2]]
l[0] = 4
print(x)
>>> [[4], [4]]
```

You can overcome this by using either a new variable or a `copy.deepcopy()`

```python
>>> import copy
>>> l = [2]
>>> x = [copy.deepcopy(l), l]
>>> print(x)
[[2], [2]]
>>> l[0] = 4
>>> print(x)
[[2], [4]]
```